# Mouse event for two elements, one above the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services

If I have two elements, one above another, would I be able to recognize click events for both elements? I've been looking around stackoverflow and have found `pointer-events:none`, but that passes the pointer event to the element underneath, while I would like both.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the top element fire the bottom element

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">
<div class="b">
```

**CSS**

```
.a {
  position: absolute;
}
.b { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.a').click(function(){
  ...
});

$('.b').click(function(){
  $('.a').click();
  ...
});
```